# A simple question about one dimesional projections

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Does any one-dimensional projection in matrix $\mathbb{M}_n$ has a fixed form？ and Whether there is a minimal partial isometry $u$ in $\mathbb{M}_n$ such that $u^*u=p,uu^*=q$ for any one-dimensional projections $p,q$ in matrix $\mathbb{M}_n$?  please help me!!!

Comment: If you have $P$ a one-dimensional projection let $\xi \in \mathrm{Im}(P)$ be a unit vector. Then $Px = \langle \xi, x \rangle \xi$. If you know about $K$-theory it is trivial that all $k$-dimensional projections in $M_n$ are Murray von Neumann-equivalent. If you don't know about this you have to extend a unitary between the one-dimensional spaces to a partial isometry on the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,q$ be rank one projections, meaning that there are $a,b$ of norm $1$ so that, $p=a\otimes a^*$ $q=b\otimes b^*$ (here $a^*$ is the dual of $a$ via the scalar product). If you write it out you find:
$$px=\langle a,x\rangle a\quad qx=\langle b,x\rangle b$$

Then with $u=a\otimes b^*$ you have $u^*=b\otimes a^*$. It follows
$$uu^*=a\otimes b^*\cdot b\otimes a^*=b^*(b)\cdot a\otimes a^*=\|b\|^2 p=p$$
similarly
$$u^*u=b\otimes a^*\cdot a\otimes b^* =\|a\|^2b\otimes b^*=q$$